# mouseDoubleClickEvent with QLabel

Tags: python, pyside2

How can I implement the mouseDoubleClickEvent()?

This is the line of code:

self.ui.label_3.mouseDoubleClickEvent(self)

I always get the error;

```
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.mouseDoubleClickEvent' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.mouseDoubleClickEvent(MainWindow)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.mouseDoubleClickEvent(PySide2.QtGui.QMouseEvent)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not overriding the mouseDoubleClickEvent method but are invoking it incorrectly.

In general override the mouseDoubleClickEvent method should be done in the following way:

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel


class Label(QLabel):
    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
        print("mouseDoubleClickEvent")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    label = Label(text="Qt is awesome!!!", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    label.resize(640, 480)
    label.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But in your case it seems that it is not possible since you need to inherit from the QLabel and replace it. In that case it is better to use an eventFilter:

```py
    self.ui.label_3.installEventFilter(self)

def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj is self.ui.label_3 and event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
        print("MouseButtonDblClick")
    return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```